# How to move to the next interaction in a loop if the previous one got an empty dataframe?

Tags: r, loops

I want to extract from the online database OBIS all the species occurrence records for a group of polygons. The number of polygons is to large to get all of them at the same time so I thought to use a loop to achieve it. The problem I'm facing is due the fact that not all polygons have records so the result is an empty dataframe and the loop stops. I tried to use the control-flow "if" but is not working. Can I get what I need with a loop? [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0nqvxylib2sbqz/smaller.zip?dl=0) is a shorter version of the shapefile I'm using.

```
 library(robis)
 library(maptools)
 library(mregions)
 library(plyr)

    polygons <- readShapeSpatial("~/smaller.shp")

    occurrence_list = list()
    for (i in 1:length(polygons)){
      wkt_polygons <- mr_as_wkt(polygons[i,])
      occur <- occurrence(geometry=wkt_polygons)
      if(is.null(occur) next
      occur$i<-i
      occurrence_list[[i]] <- occur
    }

    data <- dplyr::bind_rows(occurrence_list)
```

Comment: Where is package `robis` from?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, you can find the package here https://github.com/iobis/robis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the required result should look like, but this might work:

```
occurrence_list = list()
for (i in 1:length(polygons)){
  wkt_polygons <- mr_as_wkt(polygons[i,])
  occur <- occurrence(geometry=wkt_polygons)
  if(nrow(occur) > 0) {
    occur$i<-i
    occurrence_list[[length(occurrence_list) + 1]] <- occur
  }
}

data <- dplyr::bind_rows(occurrence_list)
```

Comment: Thank you! The result I get with this code is the one I expected.